# C++ LDAP Checking if a user is a member of a specific group

Tags: c++, ldap

Been trying this for a while so far with no success, so hoping someone can help out (and that I'm not far off!). I just want to return whether a user is a member of a specific group through LDAP. So far I have the below code;

```
int authMethod = LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE;
LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ULONG getOptSuccess = 0;
ULONG connectSuccess = 0;
INT returnCode = 0;
int retSearch = 0;
LDAPMessage *res;
int num_entries = 0, num_refs = 0;

pLdapConnection = ldap_init((char*)m_Hostname.GetString(), LDAP_PORT);

returnCode = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,
    LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
    (void*)&version);


// Connect to the server.
connectSuccess = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

// Bind
returnCode = ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection, (char*)m_Username.GetString(), (char*)m_Password.GetString(), authMethod);

// Attempt to search for user
retSearch = ldap_search_s(pLdapConnection, "dc=as,dc=local", LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(sAMAccountName = examplename))", NULL, NULL, &res);
```

All of this works so far, up until the searching part, for example - I want to search for a user "username" in group "Technical". I've tried things like the below;

```
retSearch = ldap_search_s(pLdapConnection, "dc=as,dc=local", LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(sAMAccountName=username)(memberof=CN=Technical))",
    nullptr, 0, &pSearchResult);
```

That does not return anything, so I've tried searching more and the only thing similar I've found is - [LDAP Finding Members of a group PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920534/ldap-finding-members-of-a-group-php) but it's in PHP and I cannot seem to transfer that over to C++ so far.

Any help in the right direction would be helpful as I cannot work it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your filter should be something like:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourUserName)
  (memberOf=CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com))
```

To include membership due to group nesting:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourUserName)
  (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=YourGroup,ou=Users,dc=YourDomain,dc=com))
```

The numbers `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` are an extended match.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems pretty close. On match should I be getting a return from ldap_count_entries or ldap_count_references? As I'm getting 0 back from both of them, but I'm hoping to get a return value to let me know if anything is returned or not.

Comment: The search return value `retSearch` is `LDAP_SUCCESS`?

Comment: Yes it does return as LDAP_SUCCESS, but both seem to show 0. Connection with user/pass seems to work, but the search returns 0 although the username and group are correct.